# What did Zeno destroy?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

I'm confused about what Zeno destroyed for killing Zamasu, did he destroy just the Earth, the entire Universe, or the 12 universes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming your referring to episode 67. Zeno said the following:

> A world like this must be destroyed.

---

> I believe it safe to assume that the earth was destroyed but not the
>   entire universe. If Zeno did destroy the entire universe there
>   wouldn't have been a way to use the time machine to go back and get
>   him because time is a component of a universe. No universe, no time,
>   no travel by time machine.

---

The above was my original answer to this question until I read chapter 18 of the manga and Whis said the following below.

[image: Chapter 18]

Based off of this and prior knowledge we received in the anime that the King of All has destroyed universes before. I now believe it is safe to say that he actually destroyed the entire Universe in that timeline.

Previously I argued that if a Universe doesn't exist time can't exist either. And this is stepping away from anime for a bit but physics tells us that

> Matter cannot be created or destroyed only transformed

So in summation after a little research I've come to a different conclusion.

**Even if existence as we define it comes to an end. Time does not, we may lose the capacity to quantify or comphrehend it but time is everpresent.**

I can honestly believe that this is a valid answer.

Comment: what makes it confusing it's that Zeno remained there as if the whole universe were the same and there would be no point to go somewhere else, plus that they show Zamasu spreading out to space, plus Gowasu saying Zamasu pretends to become the universe itself, plus if the 12 universes remained intact, shouldnt Zeno remain in that timeline to watch over those 12 universes instead of allowing to be taken to the present timeline where there is already a Zeno?

Comment: Well a couple of things I picked out. Firstly Gowasu didn't say that Zamasu pretends to become the Universe itself he said that he intends to. Meaning that it was a work in progress which got stopped by Zeno. Plus when Zeno said this world must destroyed. I'm pretty sure it would clearly pointed out if the universe was destroyed instead. As far as we know that hasn't actually happened in present tense yet.

Comment: Lastly as far as Zeno leaving his timeline to go to the other timeline with the other Zeno. I don't get that myself but I infer that Zeno's angel aka Whis' dad would come and get him should the need arise. If Whis can time travel so can his father who is clearly more powerful. In addition a general tone with gods in the franchise from beerus, to king kai there is a running trend of things that don't get taken quite as serious. They are gods afterall.

Comment: Him destroying the universe would have no effect on time. Because there are still other universes. All he would have destroyed is universe 7. Not to mention the fact that if only the Earth was destroyed they wouldn't be able to have such a casual conversation. Because hey would be in space.

Comment: How would destroying a universe not consist of destroying time in that universe? Time is a component of the life cycle of existence, if a universe is gone then time no longer exists in that plane along with  life, matter, space etc. Conversing casually in space is impossible? Can you express how they could converse in nothingness itself? Why nothing-ness is bright-white instead of absent of all light? Or how it's possible for time to continue in a state of non-existence? The only possible answer is that time continues. And time can't continue unless that universe exists.

Comment: @KazRodgers Time would surely be more than just the universe itself. It would encompass the multiverse. Just because that universe is destroyed does not mean that time doesn't flow within the multiverse. Otherwise how would anybody time travel if Zeno had destroyed universes previously? I can't explain how they would converse in nothingness itself. But it makes more sense for them to converse in nothingness than for them to converse in space because it is already explained that Saiyans can't survive in space, refer to the Fukkatsu no F portion of the story with regards to Vegeta.

Comment: @KazRodgers And to add to this Zeno says せかい(Sekai) which can mean world but it can also mean the universe. I mean the fact is evident that it wasn't merely just Earth as if it was just Earth then the scene would have played out exactly like how Freeza destroyed Earth. They wouldn't be floating in a white space. Also. Why are you assuming that him destroying the universe would destroy time? He could have just reduced the universe to its base elements which is why we see those random rainbow streaks in the white space.

Comment: @KazRodgers And if you destroy Earth you don't destroy time there. So why should that be any different on a larger scale?

Comment: @MDavies, you drive a hard bargain. I guess it's safe to say that our answers differ a great deal but we don't have substantial evidence to consider either a `fact`. I wonder if Toriyama will shed light on this since we are headed to filler-central soon. In the mean-time out of respect for the rules I have to delete this answer. Thanks for pointing out the flaws in my logic.

Comment: I know that this comment thread is long but after reading the newest chapter of super. I am inclined to change my arguement. Whis's comment changed my situation entirely. Since Zeno has been portrayed consistently as a Universe destroyer opposed to a world destroyer. It's only proper to continue in the line of thinking that whis stated. If a world gives me a problem. That whole universe goes. Not just that world specifically.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to believe Zeno destroyed all the universes in order to start again because Zamasu killed all the gods—that is, the Kaioshins of other universes. Zeno, being the childlike being that he is, decided to reset rather than try to find a way to revive everyone that had died (which I suppose he would not do since it's "unnatural"). So, aside from the universe being corrupted by Zamasu, each universe was essentially without guidance.

When Goku and Trunks go to retrieve future Zeno, you could see that he wasn't floating in space space, but an odd, distorted, white/blank space. This doesn't confirm whether or not he destroyed other universes, but it would kinda be an explanation as to why Zeno is okay with traveling with Goku.

Answer (score 1):

I think what Zeno did was possibly destroy all matter in universe 7, or at least broke it down so it could eventually form or birth a whole new universe. So the way I see it, he did not destroy space time, he merely broke down all matter in that universe so it could start anew. As for why he left the rest of the universes behind to go to the present with Goku doesn't make sense to me. I guess one could argue that maybe he destroyed matter in all universes to reset everything for a new start, and would have to wait a very long time for matter to form into 12 new universes, similar to how our own universe took an estimated 15 billion years to get to where it is now from the Big Bang. So maybe he left that universe behind to go with Goku to the present because he knew he'd have nothing to do for billions of years. Just an idea...

I also think it's reasonable to assume he had to at least destroy all matter in universe 7 since Zamasu had begun trying to take it over. I would also think that Zamasu was trying to take over all universes since that was his plan originally, so maybe Zeno had a reason to destroy all matter in all universes since Zamasu was spreading so rapidly....

Comment: I'm tempted to mark this answer as accepted, but even if there are some averagely known dragon ball youtubers claiming it destroyed one universe, there is another claiming he destroyed the whole timeline with its 12 universes, which means I'm still confused but I'm not the only one. Besides, indeed in the anime they said he destroyed the "world" which makes it even more confusing

Answer (score 1):

In the anime , Zeno states that a world like this should not exist and destroys the place.
Since it states "world" and since the future timeline is different from the past timeline in DBS, I believe he destroyed the future timeline's earth, although I am just assuming this from the fact it says "world" in the anime.